# Axios 'GET' request is pending but it never reaches the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using axios on my React app to get data from my server (Node). My GET request stays pending in chrome developer tools and does not reach the server if I refresh the app on the provided route (e.g., http://localhost:3000/category/5d68936732d1180004e516cb). However, if I redirect from the home page, it will work.

I have tried different variations of making sure I end my responses on the server end of things.

Several posts have had related problems (e.g., [request not reaching the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072015/request-not-reaching-the-server), [POST request does not reach the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784782/post-request-does-not-reach-the-server)) but unfortunately not been helpful in my situation.

Here is my main call in my react app:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('I am here!'); // this gets executed even on page refresh
    axios.get(`/api/categories/${this.props.id}`)
      .then( (res) => {
        this.setState({
          title: res.data.category.title,
          module: res.data.category.module ? true : false,
          ...res.data
        })
      }, (err) => console.log(err))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

On my back end I call this function after going through user verification:

```
module.exports.publishedCategories = async function(req, res) {
  try {    
    // some code that I removed for clarity
    res.json({
      category,
      children,
      flagged: flaggedCategories
    });
  } catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.sendStatus(500).end();
    }
}
```

Some more code regarding my routing:

index.js

```
<Route
    path='/category/:id'
    render={ (props) => {
       return <Category id={props.match.params.id} />
    }}
/>
```

I do not get any error messages...

Comment: one of multiple reasons may be cache issue and internet speed.

Comment: can you be more specific about cache issues? it just seems odd that an axios.get request that I use elsewhere does not experience the same problems. I doubt it is my internet speed.

Comment: Is your front end and backend both on port 3000?

Comment: No. They are on different ports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overzealous with my initial solution of switching to `componentDidUpdate()`. This only worked for page refreshes but not for redirects (i.e., I had the reverse problem). My final solution is as follows:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    setTimeout( async () => {
      this.loadCategory();
    }, 10)
  }

  componentDidUpdate = async (props, state) => {
    if(props.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.loadCategory();
      return;
    }
    return false;
  }

  loadCategory = async () => {
    let result = await axios.get(`/api/categories/${this.props.match.params.id}`);
    this.setState({
      title: result.data.category.title,
      module: result.data.category.module ? true : false,
      ...result.data
    });
  }
```

I am not sure why adding a setTimeout() works for componentDidMount().

As per the documentation `componentDidUpdate()`, it is good for netork updates however you need to compare prior props with current props.

Unforunately I am not sure how to get around the setTimeout() hack but it seems to work.